# How to create a shell alias with parameters

Tags: shell, awk, grep, alias, cat

I need to check a lot of configuration files and like to `cat` them without the lines beginning with comments.

I am typing the following in the shell:

```
egrep -v '^[[:blank:]]*#' *filename* | awk 'NF'
```

which works:

```
$ egrep -v '^[[:blank:]]*#' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | awk 'NF'
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
}
```

instead of typing it each time, I wish to make an alias on my batch, but I can't find a way to do so (neither to find info on the net for that :( ).

I tried :

```
testfunc () { egrep -v '^[[:blank:]]*#' $0 | awk 'NF'; }
```

but it doesn't work :-(

```
$ testfunc /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

nothing is returned :( 
What do I miss ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alias` cannot get parameters. Instead, use a function, which in fact is what you are already using.

For this, use `$1` and not `$0` as you are doing (`$1` means the first argument you provide).

All together, this should work:

```
testfunc () { egrep -v '^[[:blank:]]*#' "$1" | awk 'NF'; }
                                         ^^
```

Note also that this could be handled with a single `awk`:

```
testfunc () {  awk '!/^\s*#/ && NF' "$1"; }
                    ^^^^^^^     ^^
                       |        lines with some content
lines not starting with (spaces) + #
```

Comment: +1 the second function doesn't work (missing [;] + doesn't work :@ )The 1st one works fine, thanks :)